# android- how to put icon on google map api 2

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I need to add icon to my map, something like image below :
[image]

this is my code :

```
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("resturan")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.a2));
```

I manage to add icon to my map but it's just an icon with no border and it doesn't look nice , in the above image , there is a border around each image , this is what i need

How can I add this border to my icons ?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog post I wrote on how to put images inside the `InfoWindow` in an asynchronous way:

[Guide: Google Maps V2 for Android : Update InfoWindow with an Image Asynchronously](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=1031)

You can see there how to specify a layout for your `InfoWindow` as well, in the layout you could add the borders to your image using the `margins` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can customize your map icon before apply in the map.

```
public Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context) {
    View marker = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).
                   inflate(R.layout.map_popup, your_parent_layout,false);
    TextView tv_location_name = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.tv_location_name);
    TextView tv_event_status = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_status);
    TextView tv_event_name = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_name);

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    marker.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    marker.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
    marker.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(marker.getMeasuredWidth(), marker.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    marker.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```